# What is the best approach in terms of security when making a request on a resource server that uses Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

What is the best approach in terms of security when making a request on a resource server that uses Oauth2 ?

With four actors :

- a JavaScript client
- a client server which distributes the Javascript client and allows to obtain an Oauth2 token with the Authorization Code process
- an authentication server
- a resource server

First approach: Use the client server as a proxy to access the resource server from the Javascript client, and not expose the JWT token.

Second approach: Expose the JWT token and access the resource server directly from the JavaScript client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1: JAVASCRIPT ONLY APPROACH**

This is used when you want to follow an SPA architecture, with no web back end and deploying the SPA's static content to a content delivery network. But it has these issues and is no longer really viable:

- Increased concerns about XSS and threats in the browser
- Due to recent browser cookie restrictions, user experience and multi-tab browsing only work reliably if you store long lived tokens in local storage, which is bad from a security viewpoint

**2: REFRESH TOKEN IN A COOKIE APPROACH**

A good next step is to store refresh tokens strongly encrypted in an HTTP only secure cookie, with only short lived access tokens in the browser:

- Silent token renewal works reliably since you do not need to rely on the third party SSO cookie to get a new access token

This is a pretty secure model, but there are still some concerns about access tokens being intercepted, either at rest or in flight. The main mitigations are to keep access tokens short lived, unreadable and store them only in memory.

**3: NO TOKENS IN THE BROWSER APPROACH**

It is common once you have implemented this option to also use cookies for access tokens, which is currently considered the browser best practice:

- Use only the most secure `SameSite=strict` cookies in the browser
- Fewer concerns around cross site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities

Browser exploits to send secure cookies via session hijacking are still possible so it is recommended to also follow best practices to protect against XSS risks.

**SEPARATING WEB AND API CONCERNS**

You can get recommended security and also an SPA architecture by implementing Website security in an API, which is an evolution of the third approach. It is a tricky flow, but if interested, have a look at the Curity resources on this topic:

- [The Token Handler Pattern](https://curity.io/product/token-service/oauth-for-web/)

Comment: Thanks, for the first approach I think it's actually the Token Handler Pattern. The SPA uses a server A connected to an authorization server B to log the user in (using Authorization code grant) then store the tokens (jwt and refresh) into the user session and returns a secure session cookie (same site + http only). Then when the SPA want to acces to any resource server API, it passes through the server A that acts like a reverse proxy. So the tokens are never exposed.

Comment: With the second approach the SPA makes requests directly to he resource server, but it is still connected to the server A to retrieve the JWT token stored into session before each request to the resource server. The refresh token is not exposed and the JWT has a very short life (5 minutes). But yes it is still potentially vulnerable to XSS and the token is also exposed in the requests made by the browser in the header.

Comment: Cool - I updated my answer based on your comments - refresh token in a cookie is definitely needed - so either option 2 or 3 in my answer are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I agree that a refresh token in a cookie is absolutely necessary if you use that approach, because although the access token and the refresh token can be fetched from the backend session at the start, that session have a short lifespan compared to the refresh token. So the session can be expired but the backend can still be used to retrieve a new access token with the refresh token, anytime the user get an 401 Unauthorized HTTP code from a ressource server. I actually implemented that approach in my app 6 month ago, it was a bit tricky but it works fine !